# Loop through child elements in html element

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have several elements with the same class. But in one of the classes there is a inputfield with `type="search"`. And I want to put focus on that select element. There are also multiple `type="search" elements in the DOM. So I can't run through the DOM and select it. I need to find it in the containing class.

```
const container = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('md-select-menu-container'));

for (const htmlElement of container) {
    console.log(htmlElement);

}
```

This shows all the elements `md-select-menu-container`. So I want to loop through all the children (and the children elements of those child elements) and search for a element with the attribute `type="search"`.

My question is how do I write a for loop that loops through all available child elements of a html element.

Comment: Please insert some part of your html code too.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better for you instead of searching all classes and find element with `type=search`, search elements with that attribute. Use this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[type="search"]');
```

Then loop through them and find your specific element.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to loop to get the child.

Try `document.querySelector('.md-select-menu-container > input[type=search]'`

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.md-select-menu-container > input[type=search]');
el.focus();
```

```html
<div class="md-select-menu-container">Div 1</div>
<div class="md-select-menu-container">Div 2
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search 1..."/>
</div>
<div class="md-select-menu-container">Div 1</div>

<div class="md-select-menu-container">Div 3</div>

<input type="search" placeholder="Search 2..."/>
```

**OR:** May be want something like the following:

```js
const container = document.querySelectorAll('.md-select-menu-container');

for (const htmlElement of container) {
  const children = htmlElement.children;
  for (const el of children) {
    if(el.getAttribute('type') === 'search')
      el.focus();;
  }    
}
```

```html
<div class="md-select-menu-container">Div 1</div>
<div class="md-select-menu-container">Div 2
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search 1..."/>
</div>
<div class="md-select-menu-container">Div 1</div>

<div class="md-select-menu-container">Div 3</div>

<input type="search" placeholder="Search 2..."/>
```